# Python Fabric config file (~/.fabricrc) is not used

Tags: python, fabric

I'm developing a task where I need to have a few pieces of information specific to the environment.

I setup the ~/.fabricrc file but when I run the task via command line, the data is not in the env variable

I don't really want to add the -c config to simplify the deployment.

in the task, I'm calling

> env.cb_account

and I have in ~/.fabricrc

> cb_account=foobar

it throws **AttributeError**

Has anybody else run into this problem?

I found the information when I view env outside of my function/task. So now the question is how do I get that information into my task? I already have 6 parameters so I don't think it would be wise to add more especially when those parameters wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Overrode the "env" variable via parameter in the function. Dumb mistake.